# Is Jyn Erso based on Jan Ors and/or Kyle Katarn?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, inspiration, rogue-one

[Jyn Erso](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jyn_Erso) from *[Rogue One](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One)* seems to have several similarities to [Jan Ors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jan_Ors) and [Kyle Katarn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn), both of whom are Legends status characters.

Jyn Erso and Jan Ors comparison:

- Their names sound similar; "Jan" vs "Jyn" and "Ors" vs "Erso", it's almost the exact same name
- They are both young, female, humans
- They both have affiliations with the Rebellion
- > They both help steal the plans for the first Death Star

Have the filmmakers or Lucasfilm **commented** about any inspiration for her character? Is she based on Jan Ors? Is she based on Kyle Katarn? Or maybe both?

Comment: I don't see a point to these questions tbh. "Will Disney ever explicitly admit to drawing inspiration from Legends for specific ideas?" Seems to me that answer is "no". So beyond that initial statement on Disney's policy regarding canon & Legends, we probably won't get anymore words on the matter.

Comment: I doubt we'll get a definitive answer but there's some interesting commentary here: https://moviepilot.com/posts/3859966

Answer (score 6):

### Probably not

A 2016 [*Vanity Fair* article](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/12/star-wars-rogue-one-john-knoll-visual-effects) discusses the genesis of *Rogue One*'s story, and casts some serious doubt on this theory:

1. John Knoll, the Industrial Light & Magic executive who first pitched the story that would become *Rogue One*, came up with the idea for the story during production on *Revenge of the Sith*, when the aborted live-action series [*Star Wars: Underworld*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Underworld) was still on the table:

   > It was around that time, while in Sydney working on what everybody believed would be the final film in the franchise, *Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*, that Knoll first heard that story development had begun on a Star Wars live-action television series.
   >
   > "I thought, Oh, that's an interesting idea. I started thinking about what might be fun stories to tell in the Star Wars universe that might make a good one-hour episode."
   >
   > One of Knoll's immediate thoughts was related to the opening crawl of A New Hope—the screen-filling, scene-setting prologue text that rolled diagonally upward into the cosmos at the start of the film.
   >
   > > *...Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire. During the battle, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire’s ultimate weapon, the DEATH STAR....*
2. Knoll had the Jyn Erso character in mind from the very beginning (emphasis mine):

   > "I have three daughters who grew up while I was working on the special editions and the prequels," he says. "They got to be big Star Wars fans. And, you know, I would see them identifying with a lot of the male characters and I just thought: Star Wars could use more good strong female leads. **I wrote Jyn in as the protagonist from the very beginning**. It felt right for the story."
3. As Pablo Hidalgo confirmed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/808928964035153920) shortly after this article was published, the name "Jyn Erso" also came from Knoll:

   [image]

   > **@Burzol** Pablo, but that name, Jyn Erso, also came from John Knoll?
   >
   > **@pablohidalgo** Yep.

   In [a 2017 interview](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/the-secret-origin-of-jyn-ersos-name-revealed-by-rogue-one-mastermind-160705522.html) with Yahoo! Movies, Knoll discusses where the name "Jyn Erso" came from; apparently her first name came from several ladies in his family:

   > When it came to naming her, Knoll didn’t have to look far for inspiration. "My youngest daughter is Jane, and my wife is Jen, so [Jyn] is sort of mashup of them. And growing up my aunt was Aunt Ginny, [short] for Virginia, so there's a little bit of that, too. It’s a mix up of a lot of my favorite women in my life."
4. As the article states, and as Hidalgo confirms on Twitter [earlier](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/808927978696691713) in that thread I linked to earlier), Knoll didn't know about *Dark Forces* when he wrote the treatment; he learned about it from Hidalgo after he pitched the concept as a feature film in 2013:

   > Knoll reached out to Lucasfilm's Story Group, the anointed story-development executives who manage and defend the *Star War*s canon. Story Group executive Pablo Hidalgo — a founding member of the Star Wars Fanboy Association who now worked for Lucasfilm — informed Knoll that, actually, the theft of the Death Star plans had been covered a couple of times already: a 1981 NPR radio drama and a 1995 first-person shooter computer game, *Star Wars: Dark Forces*.

Given all of these things, it seems *exceptionally* unlikely that Jyn was modelled on either Katarn or Jan Ors.

Comment: Or the porn star Jayna Oiso-looks like Felicity. name probably came from her being someone's favorite...

Comment: @KingofNES Since the name "Jyn Erso" came long before Felicity Jones was cast in the role, that would be a truly astonishing coincidence

Comment: Yeah, but Jayna was around before Jyn :D

Comment: Jan Ors comes from way back in 2002, Revenge of the Sith is from 2005.