# Why didn't Kyle steal the Death Star plans?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, video-games, rogue-one

A popular Legends character emerging from the *Dark Forces* and *Jedi Knight* games is **Kyle Katarn**.  One of his feats was teaming up with Jan Ors to successfully **steal the plans for the first Death Star** (well, if you as the player didn't muck it up).

[image]

Now, it seems clear that *Rogue One* main character Jyn Erso is at least in part an homage to Jan Ors (although this has not been [confirmed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/is-jyn-erso-based-on-jan-ors-and-or-kyle-katarn) yet, it seems).

Likewise, it seems like Cassian Andor from *Rogue One* could have been inspired by Kyle Katarn, but the naming is less obvious here.  Even if he was, my question is:

**Why wasn't Kyle Katarn explicitly used in *Rogue One*?**

Obviously, the new Star Wars continuity is not bound to use anything from Legends canon.  But still, Katarn was a popular character and I'm sure some fans must have been disappointed not to see him brought to life on the big screen.

Comment: Because not enough people signed [the petition](https://www.change.org/p/gareth-edwards-bring-kyle-katarn-to-rogue-one-and-or-make-it-canon)?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124445/51379

Comment: @Adamant : I already linked to that in my question.  :-)

Comment: There had been too many Male Leads in Star Wars. Time for more Female Leads. Also, I'd say Kyle Katarn and Jan Ors had been subsumed into Kanan Jarrus and Hera Syndulla. So Rogue One writers look for other inspiration sources.

Comment: @pepoluan : I'm all for female leads.  I'm not asking why he wasn't the lead.  I'm asking why he wasn't used at all (at least in name).

Comment: @pepoluan - Kyle Katarn as Kanan Jarrus, *maybe*. But Jan Ors as Hera Syndulla? Hera Syndulla is a Twi’lek pilot, born on Ryloth, whose name doesn’t sound much like Jan Ors, and who didn’t participate in the mission to steal the Death Star plans (though she may have been in the battle). Jan Ors is a human spy, born on Alderaan, who *did* help steal the Death Star plans, and whose name sounds a lot more like Jyn Erso.

Comment: @Adamant Kanan also didn't participate in the mission to steal the Death Star plans. What's your point? Further: Hera's a skilled pilot (like Jan), one of Hera's outfit is a pair of goggles (like Jan), and she's in love with a reluctant Force User (like Jan).

Comment: @Praxis because Jyn Erso is not Jan Ors. The name is perhaps just a nod to Legends, but that's it. Also note Jyn's father's name: Galen. Which was another nod to Legends' Galen Marek.

Comment: @pepoluan - Kanan is also not so fitting, but the name is  closer.

Comment: Aside from odd music and non-OT sound design, the lack of Kyle Katarn was IMHO the biggest flaw of the movie.

Comment: @Adamant Hera Syndulla is totally a Jan Ors. Her name and species might be different, but everything else is nearly a carbon copy, especially her personality and a slightly complicated relationship with one formerly-ashamed Jedi

Comment: @Petersaber : I'm not a fan of Michael Giacchino's scores.  I find that he relies on repetitive riffs that are always somehow at odds with the tone or scene.

Answer (score 1):

Disney is very carefully separating Disney Star Wars from Star Wars Legends.  I was disappointed that they didn't name Ben Solo as Jacen Solo, as they essentially followed similar arcs, and Ben wouldn't be a name especially dear to either Leia (Kinobi only being a contact she had to reach on Tatooine) or Han (Just some crazy old man who turned off the tractor beam then got sliced in half).

While the characters might have been similar, they weren't the same at all.  They had different backgrounds, got the plans different ways, and died different deaths.

Disney created a new character, perhaps inspired by an older character, but in order to have the full flexibility to write the character they wanted to write, they just left Kyle in the Legends.

Comment: Please note that ALL Star Wars asset and Canon are managed _fully_ by Lucasfilm, not by Disney. Disney have no say in what's canon and what's not.

Comment: @Disney - Sorry, could you elaborate? Lucasfilm was purchased by Disney, and is now part of Disney, so I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Adamant I think he means that Lucasfilm is still somewhat separate from Disney Corporate Itself;  the idea is that Lucasfilm still has control over Star Wars while Disney holds the deeds.  I would contend that Lucasfilm has to make money for Disney, and Disney said they need to make more films, and Lucasfilm realized they needed room to maneuver to make fresh money for Disney, because any money made before the purchase is already spent.  And Disney wants new money.

Comment: Regarding affinity for Ben -- Leia would have learned that Obi Wan was close to her brother, mother and father, and that he escorted her (as an infant) to safe adoptive parents. Worthy namesake I'd say